# Setting systemd containers in Ubuntu

Tags: systemd

How to setup basic systemd-nspawn container in Ubuntu? I see only Fedora based in the net. I'm very new to this and want to setup a container and spawn a process in it.

Answer (score 3):

There are examples in the manpage:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/systemd-nspawn.1.html

The example is for debian, but something like the following works for a minimal container using vivid.

```
debootstrap --arch=amd64 vivid ~/vivid-tree/
systemd-nspawn -D ~/vivid-tree/
```